# Divide two columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, indexing, divide

I would like to divide the values of two columns in a df in python.

So far I have

```
df3['Result'] = df3[1_x]/df3[1_y]
```

The columns formed after an inner merge. I keep on getting the error
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `df3['Result'] = df3['1_x']/df3['1_y']`?

Comment: Variable names can't start with a digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing single quotes for column names `1_x` and `1_y`:

```
df3['Result'] = df3['1_x'] / df3['1_y']
#                   ^   ^        ^   ^
```

Reproducible error:

```
>>> 1_x
  File "<ipython-input-4828-dea8fc3e99c1>", line 1
    1_x
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal
```

Comment: I entered the single quotes but I get the error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'. The columns consist of numbers, so I do not understand why it is being read as a string.

Comment: What is the output of `df3.info()`

Comment: As you can see `2 1_y 56445 non-null object` is not int type. Try `df3['1_x'] / df3['1_y'].astype(int)`

Comment: Then try to cast as float. `df3['1_x'] / df3['1_y'].astype(float)`

Comment: @StrawberryCherry. Why did you uncheck my answer? There is something wrong?